# What does a geometric proof look like?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, problem-solving

High school student here. I've never really had a chance to prove anything considering my current educational standing, but I am very interested in mathematics and would like a to try to prove some very basic things in the near future. Recently, I've learned that there are different types of proofs, specifically geometric ones. I'm wondering what this would look like and if this approach can be used on any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I learned high school geometry decades ago, it is the first time you see axioms and have to derive things more formally.  You are given the axioms for Euclidean geometry, which typically sound obvious because they agree with our experience.  In class various theorems are proven, often in a two column format.  The left column has statements and the right column has justifications, which can be algebraic or can be citations to axioms or theorems that have already been proven.  They are often accompanied by a diagram showing what is going on.

An example would be to prove the base angles of an isosceles triangle are equal.  You define an isosceles triangle as one having two equal sides.  The proof would show a diagram with a line cutting the triangle in half from the vertex between the equal sides like the one below.  The small lines cutting the two sides indicate they are equal.  You would specify that $CH$ is a median, that it connects that vertex to the midpoint of the opposite side.  Presumably you have shown you can construct this point.  The proof would be something like
$$\begin {array} {l l}CH=CH&\text{Same segment}\\AC=BC&\text{Given}\\AH=HB&\text{By construction}
\\ACH \cong BCH&\text{side-side-side}\\ \angle A=\angle B&\text{corresponding parts of congruent triangles}\end {array}$$

[image]

Comment: I've taken geometry and encountered proofs like this before. I was just wondering if a similar approach can be used for any sort of problem. Like in number theory for example.

Comment: Certainly it can.  It usually is not because it is rather clumsy.  This is a good teaching tool to get students thinking carefully about justifying the statements they make.  As you go on in math, proofs are not as careful.  The goal is to convince the audience that you could produce a proof like this if needed but you are trying to cover too much ground to make writing out the details worthwhile.  In number theory we might say given $n$, let its prime factorization be $p^aq^b...r^c$ and not bother to cite the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I think I should do more research into how proofs are constructed. Answer accepted based on the info in this comment.

Comment: It's done with symbollic logic a lot where the axioms and laws and thereoms are spelled out.  It's not done so much with calculus or number theory or abstract algebra where concepts and applications are varied and the point of the proof is more an explanation than anything else.  If the student is sophisticated it's assumed we don't need to justify basic things over and over.

Comment: I remember from middle school that proving the equality of one of the  median/bisector/altitudes (I don't recall which one) was very difficult. It required considering two intermediate triangles that my middle school brain would have never thought of (and my current brain cannot remember).

Answer (score 1):

Well, first thing you need to understand is that the "geometric" adjective is not a well-defined thing when applied to proofs. What it refers to, loosely speaking, is a proof that is significantly easier to comprehend if accompanied by a particular picture (whether the picture is included in the proof, or left to the readers to construct for themselves).

For example, the classic [Basel Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) can be attacked from many different angles, but [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-o3eB9sfls) is a nice geometric way of looking at the problem.

A word of caution though: a picture by itself is rarely considered proof by itself. There typically needs to be some text to contextualise it, and explain how this picture deals with the result in full generality.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'll be sure to look over it. I've heard of people describing the proof of a problem like 2+2=4 to be as simple as just drawing an array. Would that be considered acceptable?

Comment: you can't really prove 2+2 = 4 without a groundwork of axioms and definitions as to what it means which usually are not the point of the class.  Numbers are defined as successors to other numbers (down to zero) and addition by applying a number of successors.  A picture of an array implies the person seeing it will no why it pertains to the concept of addition and the concept of "2" and "4".  It's .... to be continued ....

Comment: Actually proving 2+2 = 4 is a matter of axiomatically defining what natural numbers are what addition is and proving that addition is consistent and results in counting over counting.  Once that is established showing 2+2 = 4 or 145 + 2324 = 2469 isn't a matter of proof but simply of counting and saying 2+2 has to equal *something* and looking at this array dot. dot and dot. dot is dot.dot.dot.dot and that's the number we call "four".